# logout not working properly in monotouch-bindings facebook sample

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

i just downloaded the monotouch-bindings sample for facebook integration it's working fine but
clicking on **logout** button for another user login, it's not asking the credentials, it tooks previous  **credentials** and directly goes to next screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) instead. It's very easy to use JSON-based API.

There is useful JSON-data processing library [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for requests data serialization and response data deserialization.

AS a network transport it's possible to use generic [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).

Graph API + JSON.Net + HttpWebRequest together work like a charm under MonoTouch platform.