# Library to authenticate user using their Facebook and Google accounts using OAuth on Mono Droid and Mono Touch

Tags: xamarin.ios, oauth-2.0, xamarin.android

I'm very new to Mono Droid and Mono TOuch, but I would like to know if there is any library that allows me to authenticate users of my application using their Facebook and Google accounts?

I've seen some examples for the Facebook SDK on "Mono for Android" and "Mono Touch" , but since I don't need the full facebook SDK and I only need a small set of info from the user I was wondering if there is a simple library that will allow me to authenticate to any site using OAuth (I'm only interested on Google and Facebook for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try community-based implementations from [OAuth site](http://oauth.net/code/)?

About Facebook API binding: I tried Facebook API binding for MonoTouch with no success. After that I started using official JSON-based [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). It's relatively easy to implement calling of any API method. For more information about using Facebook API in MonoTouch/MonoDroid apps please see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597807/logout-not-working-propperly-in-monotouch-bindings-facebook-sample/13605682#13605682).